# PHP convert date format dd/mm/yyyy => yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, date, formatting, mktime

I am trying to convert a date from `dd/mm/yyyy => yyyy-mm-dd`. I have using the mktime() function and other functions but I cannot seem to make it work. I have managed to `explode` the original date using `'/'` as the delimiter but I have no success changing the format and swapping the `'/'` with a `'-'`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this one $old_date = "20/04/2012";
$new_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($old_date) );

Answer (score 336, accepted):

> Dates in the `m/d/y` or `d-m-y` formats are disambiguated by looking
>   at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (`/`), then the American `m/d/y` is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (`-`) or a dot (`.`), then the European `d-m-y`
>   format is assumed. Check [more here](https://devdocs.io/php/function.strtotime).

Use the default date function.

```
$var = "20/04/2012";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($var) );
```

**EDIT** I just tested it, and somehow, PHP doesn't work well with dd/mm/yyyy format. Here's another solution.

```
$var = '20/04/2012';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $var);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Here get only 1970-01-01 if i am using dd/mm/yyyy format.  mm/dd/yyyy format is ok with this code.

Comment: @SibirajPR **Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.** Check more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: This looks okay but isn't.  05/04/2045 will assume American and give the 4th of May instead of the 4th of April. It's an intermittant and dangerous mistake - as per hjpotter.  This answer should be marked as wrong.

Comment: `$var = '20/04/2012';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $var);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));` // This solution works for me for dd/mm/yy

Comment: How can strtotime() differ between mm-dd-yyyy and dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Using / to assume american format (MM/DD/YY) is dangerous because in the UK they often use / but follow the european convention (smallest to largest...DD/MM/YY.

Comment: I am Trying With the DATE datatype and it's not working, any suggestion. @hjpotter92

Comment: the second method prevents me from extra codes in API part.

Comment: I used the following code although its not the complete and better solution, but just a hack

$var = $crow['date'];
$ex = explode('/',$var);
$dd = $ex[2].'-'.$ex[1].'-'.$ex[0];

Comment: Thanks, Works perfectly. Once again thanks for the reason of that `PHP doesn't work well with 'dd/mm/YYYY' format`

Comment: This fails in cases where the date format is 'm/d/Y', resulting in a conversion to '1970-01-01'. This 'm/d/Y' date format is seen while handling Excel files in the pt-PT language. Was able to convert correctly in all cases via Baba's answer below, using DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date).

Answer (score 128):

Try Using [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', "24/04/2012");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output

```
2012-04-24
```

EDIT:

If the date is 5/4/2010 (both D/M/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY), this below method is used to convert 5/4/2010 to 2010-4-5 (both YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-M-D) format.

```
$old_date = explode('/', '5/4/2010'); 
$new_data = $old_date[2].'-'.$old_date[1].'-'.$old_date[0];
```

OUTPUT:

```
2010-4-5
```

Comment: when you have mm/dd/yyyy format and want to convert yyyy-mm-dd format,then try this.This worked for me.                                         $var1 = "03/01/2014";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $var1);
$travel_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');                                      
output = "2014-03-01"

Comment: This is the most flexible solution to all date problems. How could i miss this for all the years. Thanks!

Comment: still not correct, when u put date $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', "06/16/2022"); echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); the result will be : 2023-04-06

Answer (score 42):

Here's another solution not using date(). not so smart:)

```
$var = '20/04/2012';
echo implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $var)));
```

Comment: If it's not smart, why is it so clever.  I can't see any problems with this solution at all, and it saves screwing around with dates and localities. Guaranteed performance every time.

Comment: @tosin Very creative solution!

Comment: That would work only if they add the 0 like 05/04/2010, if they write it 5/4/2010 it won't work.

Comment: @Shadowbob, OP asked for dd/mm/yyyy conversion, so 5/4/2010 could never be the input. dd and mm naming always have 0 preceding in case of one digit date or month. This is smart solution.

Comment: @agaggi That is only if you assume 100% of people reading this solution has the same situation as the OP!

Comment: Is this method advisable? What is the disadvantage in doing so ?

Comment: @Vagabond I consider it perfectly advisable, it seems to have no performance or functionality drawbacks for me at least.

Answer (score 6):

Do this:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

But make sure 'dd/mm/yyyy' is the actual date.

Comment: This is problematic as strtotime will read a date with the `/` separator as American, i.e. `m/d/Y` whereas `-` as European `d-m-Y`. See the accepted answer's edit and php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php - Note:
Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Answer (score 1):

I can see great answers, so there's no need to repeat here, so I'd like to offer some advice:

I would recommend using a Unix Timestamp integer instead of a human-readable date format to handle time internally, then use PHP's `date()` function to convert the timestamp value into a human-readable date format for user display. Here's a crude example of how it should be done:

```
// Get unix timestamp in seconds
$current_time = date();

// Or if you need millisecond precision

// Get unix timestamp in milliseconds
$current_time = microtime(true);
```

Then use `$current_time` as needed in your app (store, add or subtract, etc), then when you need to display the date value it to your users, you can use `date()` to specify your desired date format:

```
// Display a human-readable date format
echo date('d-m-Y', $current_time);
```

This way you'll avoid much headache dealing with date formats, conversions and timezones, as your dates will be in a standardized format (Unix Timestamp) that is compact, timezone-independent (always in UTC) and widely supported in programming languages and databases.

Comment: @VitorTyburski You can't be serious? Any professional programmer with his right mind knows that storing the date as a Timestamp is the best way to deal with date formatting and adding or removing bits of time, because all it takes is to add or subtract a number of seconds to the timestamp value.

Comment: I got through some study and see your point. You're right. Although you did not answer the question.

Comment: @VitorTyburski Why did you remove your first comment then? It just shows that you're relying too much on the "delete" feature to hide your mistakes. I haven't answered the question because by the time I was on the thread, a best answer was already there, so I just wanted to make a point that using a timestamp value is good practice.

Comment: I removed the first comment wrongly, but if you wish I state it again: "Don't use timestamps, as they can lead to problems with DST, etc...". Again my comment IS WRONG, and I apologize. I simply don't remove the downvote because, I can't AND, most importantly, because you should have done a comment. If you edit your answer I will gladly remove the downvote. Sorry about that.

Comment: I have also edited my reply to reflect the fact that it's just a note, not exactly a reply to the asked question.

Comment: Someone just downvoted this answer minutes before I published my improved edit.