# PHP : Convert One date format to another for dynamic incoming data format

Tags: php

I have a problem in my application. I have to convert arriving date string to server date format. So I planned to sent date along with the date format to the model class.
Like

```
$requiredFormat='Y-m-d';
Function($givenDate,$givenFormat){
//convert given date to yyyy-mm-dd format
return $yyyy-mm-dd;
}
```

I have different types of client for my model,
My web client use one format, and my mobile clients use another format,
So I decide sent date format along with the date.

I cant use strtotime function because the format may differ in different calls.
**The required function will get 2 arguments (arrivedDate,arrivedDateFormat)
And using these 2 argument , convert the arrivedDate to YYYY-mm-dd format**
So Please provide me the best way to do this.

Comment: where's `$givenFormat` used and why is it needed when you want the format `yyyy-mm-dd` after all?

Comment: different client may access my model, so I cant exactly know correct format of the imcoming dates

Comment: My server date format is yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Force a check on the incoming date from the application, return an error if it's in the wrong format. You're overcomplicating the problem. I have never seen a date input field that didn't specify how it wanted the date formatted.

Comment: convert the incoming date into unix timestamp with strtotime and then return it with date('format', $incomingtime)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP convert date format dd/mm/yyyy => yyyy-mm-dd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306999/php-convert-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: You can try my solution. You just have to call a function and pass two parameters. The date and the format.

Comment: @Abhishek Saha, Yes I have to call a function that takes 2 argument such as arrivedDate and arrivedDateFormat, Using these 2 argument convert arrivedDate to Y-m-d format

Comment: So whats the problem now ? You can pass the format as a parameter to the function like getDate('Y-m-d',$time);

Comment: my function should be capable of handle any date format, ie My function will get any formatted date and convert it to Y-m-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my required function

```
    function convertDate($givenDate,$givenFormat)
{
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($givenFormat, $givenDate);
    $ret= $date->format('Y-m-d');
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Something like:

```
echo date('YY "-" mm "-" dd', strtotime($givenDate));
```

And also it will be good if you show us how `$givenDate` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Function mydate($givenDate,$givenFormat){
return date($givenFormat,strtotime($givenDate));
}
```

Use your format as required like `"Y-m-D" or "yyyy-mm-dd"`

and call functin like

```
 echo mydate("29-oct-2012","Y-m-d");
```

SEE **[LIVE DEMO](http://codepad.org/qbtuyOva)**

Comment: your function will return date in givenformat, But i need date in server format

Comment: echo 'Given format:mon-day-year is 8-7-2012='.mydate('8-7-2012', "Y-m-d").'Transtormed to: year-mon-day<br/>';
 
 echo 'Given format:mon-day-year is 12-8-2012='.mydate('12-8-2012', "Y-m-d").'Transtormed to: year-mon-day';.

Comment: Given format:mon-day-year is 8-7-2012=2012-07-08Transtormed to: year-mon-day
Given format:mon-day-year is 12-8-2012=2012-08-12Transtormed to: year-mon-day

Comment: @Sridhar so what is problem ? you want to convert `mon-day-year` to `year-mon-day`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18700/discussion-between-sridhar-and-jhonraymos)

Answer (score -3):

Write the function like this.
Edit: Corrected from comments

```
function getDate($givenDate,$givenFormat){
//convert given date to yyyy-mm-dd format
$newdate = date($givenFormat, strtotime($givenDate));
return $newdate;
}
```

Comment: $givenDate='05/25/2012';
$datefrmt='m/d/y';
$newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('m/d/Y',$givenDate));
echo $newdate;

Comment: strtotime('m/d/Y',$givenDate) return nothing

Comment: @Sridhar: Of coure you'll get `1970-01-01` because Abhishek Saha used `strtotime` in a wrong manner. it should be `$newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($givenDate)); `