# Check if date is in the next 3 days PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a date stored in my DB (due_date)
I am wanting to write a script that checks if the due_date is in the next 3 days

From checking online (google) i have found some code but it doesnt seem to work, see below

```
if (time() - filemtime($due_date) >= 3 * 86400) 

{
  echo" Invoice $id is due in the next 3 days<br />";
}
else
{
echo" Invoice $id not due in the next 3 days </br>";
}
```

$due_date contains a date in the format 01/01/2015

Please can someone help with this? P.s I am a newbie!

Thanks

Comment: What does ```$due_date``` contain? Is it the path to your file?

Comment: A date in the format 01/01/2015

Answer (score 2):

Use strtotime() to convert the date string to a unix timestamp, and edit your if statement accordingly:

```
$seconds_to_expire = strtotime($due_date) - time();
if ($seconds_to_expire < 3*86400) {
     ...
```

Note that dates in the m/d/y or d/m/y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307005/588879)). You may want to convert your date to a Y-m-d format instead:

```
$due_date_ymd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $due_date));
$seconds_to_expire = strtotime($due_date_ymd) - time();
if ($seconds_to_expire < 3*86400) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, however when I run this code, All invoices show "not due" but in my db i have dates of 09/03/2015 and 09/03/2015 (today and tomorrow?)

Comment: Oh, so in that just flip the statement, see my edited version above

Comment: @user4547025 check what manual says about strtotime and slashes and look at my answer

Comment: @Aviram How would i amend this for 1 day? So anything due tomorrow?

Comment: Just change the ```3*86400``` to something else. If you want a day you could write ```1 * 24 * 60 * 60```, if you want two days you could write ```2 * 24 * 60 * 60```.

Comment: @Aviram - Would this work  if (time() - strtotime($due_date) <= 86400)

Comment: It should work because 86400 equals to 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 (24 hours, 60 minutes per hour, 60 seconds per minute), but take a look at the updated code above, I made it safer.

Comment: I now have the code - if (time() - strtotime($due_date) <= 86400) but it seems to pick everything up, not dates that are tomorrow?

Comment: You need to subtract time() from the due date (like my answer above).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72515/discussion-between-user4547025-and-aviram).

Comment: I have used your code above but nothing happens when i run the script. My dates are in the format d/m/Y

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
filemtime($due_date)
```

to

```
strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $due_date))
```

you have to change `/` to `-` if the day comes first, otherwise php will assume that first is month!

Answer (score 0):

You could translate the DB date value (which is in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd') to a DateTime object and then compare:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $due_date);
$d->modify('-3 days');  // subtract 3 days from due date
if ($d < new DateTime()) {
    echo 'date is due within 3 days';
}
```

Notes:

1. `new DateTime()` will give you the current date.
2. I assume that `$due_date` is a string in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd', as you should get if it is a Date column in the database.

---

Since you commented that `$due_date` is "A date in the format 01/01/2015", you can easily ajust the code: change the format specifier in the `createFromFormat` function from `'Y-m-d'` into `'d/m/Y'`.

Answer (score 0):

`if (strtotime($due_date)+60*60*24*3 =< time()+60*60*24*3) {
 echo "Is due in the next 3 days" 
} else {
 echo "Is not due in the next 3 days"
}`