# PHP regular expression validation for date?

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation

Hi I'm trying to create a regular expression for my date field.

The date format is `MM/DD/YYYY`.

My current regular expression code is as follows

```
var RE_DATE = /^[0-12]{2}[/][0-31]{2}[/][2010-2020]{4}$/;
```

which is wrong but well... I tried. :P

May I know how to get my regular expression to check for dates and months with a 0 in front of them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10306999/1190388

Comment: not regex, but really good answer to validate a date: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19271434/5297359