# formatter asDateTime in yii2

Tags: yii2

If I have an element array like this :

```
 [PERKIRAAN_SELESAI] => 24/10/2016 09:38
```

Then I want to store into datetime format in mysql which is YYYY-MM-DD H:s,
 => 2016-10-24 09:38

How can Yii2 handle this,
Now, in beforeSave(),  I use this :

```
$this->perkiraan_selesai = Yii::$app->formatter->asDateTime(strtorime($this->PERKIRAAN_SELESAI), "php:Y-m-d H:s" );
```

But, still not working.
Please.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I see 2 errors in your code:

- `2016-10-24 09:38` date looks like a `Y-m-d H:i` format, not `Y-m-d H:s`. Check PHP [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function docs for interpretation of these letters.
- `strtorime` must be `strtotime`, but I think this typo is not in original code, just here in post.

As for your problem, check this [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306999/php-convert-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-yyyy-mm-dd). Seems that the problem is with handling of slash (`/`). Instead of replacing it with `-` manually, I found solution with native class `DateTime` much better.

Using plain PHP:

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '24/10/2016 09:38')->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Using Yii2 formatter:

```
$date = Yii::$app->formatter->asDateTime(\DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '24/10/2016 09:38'), 'php:Y-m-d H:i');
```

Just replace this date with your value.

The value of `$date` is `2016-10-24 09:38` as expected.