# How do I convert Mon May 15 2017 15:08:03 GMT 0100 (GMT Standard Time) datetime format in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to convert a javascript date object in php. I have tried to convert using my posted code, but it puts the time as 12:00:00. The date is being sent as 'Mon May 15 2017 15:08:03 GMT 0100 (GMT Standard Time)'. The idea is to insert into mysql in the format yyyy-mm-dd.

I would appreciate any help with this as it's driving me nuts. Many thanks.

**UPDATE**: I need the date & the time.

```
$intakedate = $_GET['date'];

$intakedateString = $intakedate;
$intakedateParts = explode(' ', $intakedateString, 5);
$intakedatenew =  date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($intakedateParts[2] .  ' '  . $intakedateParts[1] . ' '  . $intakedateParts[3]));
```

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306999/php-convert-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Wait so you want only yyy-mm-dd and dont waht the 12:00:00 part? Or you want instead of 12:00:00 the 15:08:03?

Comment: One line code is:

    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Mon May 15 2017 15:08:03'));

Comment: I need the date and the time

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('Mon May 15 2017 15:08:03');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

?>
```

Comment: I need the date & time to post to mysql. Thanks

Comment: Throws this error: [31-May-2017 08:45:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (Mon May 15 2017 15:08:03 GMT 0100 (GMT Standard Time)) at position 39 (S): Double timezone specification' in C:\wamp\www\domain\admin\data.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\domain\admin\data.php(35): DateTime->__construct('Mon May 15 2017...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\wamp\www\domain\admin\data.php on line 35