# CakePHP 3.6 - Find All Records Created Between Two Dates

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.6

I am looking for all records between two dates

My variables

```
 $start = '01/01/2009';
 $end = '07/24/2019';
```

I have tried

```
$gross = $this->CartOrders->find('all')->where(['placed >=' => $start])->andWhere(['placed <=' => $end])->all();
```

Query Snippet for above

```
... FROM cart_orders CartOrders 
WHERE (placed >= :c0 AND placed <= :c1) 
[params] => Array ( 
     [:c0] => Array ( [value] => 01/01/2009 [type] => datetime [placeholder] => c0 ) 
     [:c1] => Array ( [value] => 07/24/2019 [type] => datetime [placeholder] => c1 ) )
```

Results in

```
 Cake\ORM\ResultSet Object ( [items] => Array ( ) )
```

---

I have also tried

```
$gross = $this->CartOrders->find('all')->where(function($exp) use($start,$end) {
        $exp->lte('placed', $end);
        $exp->gte('placed', $start);
        return $exp;
    })->all();
```

I also have tried

```
$gross = $this->CartOrders->find('all')->where(function($q) use($start,$end) {
        return $q->between('CartOrders.placed', $start, $end, 'date');
    })->all();
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: All of those examples should work.

Comment: Let me fiddle with it somemore then...

Comment: I just tried the andWhere version, and checked the dates, if I remove the andWhere, it gives me everything created after and equal to $start, but when I add the andWhere, it gives me nothing...

Comment: Any chance it's a locale issue, and the end date is being misintpreted? Maybe try putting those dates into `FrozenDate` objects and use those in the `where`?

Comment: `MM/DD/YYYY` is most definitely the wrong format, your database most likely uses `YYYY-MM-DD` in respective date(time)-ish columns, and if it doesn't, then you need to change that, because `02/01/2019` is larger than `01/02/2019`.

Comment: It was like ndm said, it was a date format issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a date format issue.

The following solved my problem.

```
$start = '01/01/2009';
$end = '07/24/2019';

$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $start);
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $end);

$gross = $this->CartOrders->find('all')->where([
     'placed >=' => $start->format('Y-m-d')
])->andWhere([
     'placed <=' => $end->format('Y-m-d')
])->all();
```

This link helped

[PHP convert date format dd/mm/yyyy => yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306999/php-convert-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 2):

Use **QueryExpression**

```
use Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression;

$query = $this->CartOrders->find()
->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) use ($start,$end){
    return $exp->between('placed', $start, $end);
});
```

Probably add a time at condition if the user tried to search within the same day

```
return $exp->between('placed', $start . " 00:00:00", $end . " 23:59:59");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$this->CartOrders->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
        'date(placed) BETWEEN "'.$start.'" AND "'.$end.'"')));
```

It's an unorthodox solution but its something that has worked for multiple scenarios for me

Comment: Please never ever insert dynamic data into flat array values, this is a possible SQL injection vulnerability! Always use the `key => value` syntax, safe expressions, or bindings!

Comment: In case this is better
````$this->CartOrders->find('all',
  'conditions' => array('CartOrders.placed between ? and ?' => array($start_date, $end_date)));````

Comment: That would be better, yes, but the question is about CakePHP 3.x, that style is for CakePHP 2.x, it's not supported in 3.x anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->set('gross',$this->CartOrders-> find(
                'all', array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'CartOrders.placed >=' => $start,
                        'CartOrders.placed <=' => $end
                    ))
            ));  // here gross is a variable to store the data from DB and CartOders is the Model name
```

Comment: How is this supposed to solve the problem? That snippet would produce the exact same query as the examples in the question.