# How do I check if a date range is in between another date range in PHP

Tags: php, date, date-range

So I have the first date range like this: 03/07/2019 - 06/08/2019.
And I have another second date range like this: 30/07/2019 - 01/08/2019.
How can I check if the second date range belongs to the first date range in PHP?

Comment: Update: Ok have got the answer: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/493894/check-whether-one-date-range-is-between-another-date-range

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sql query that can help you

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Comment: There is nothing in the question that says it's database related, but you might be correct.

Comment: but this is the data from a submitted form, not db data :(

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to convert date from `d/m/y` to `y-m-d` ( you can take reference from [PHP convert date format dd/mm/yyyy => yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306999/php-convert-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-yyyy-mm-dd) ) and then can use below code as:

```
$firstStartDate = strtotime('2019-07-03');
$firstEndDate = strtotime('2019-08-06');
$secondstartDate = strtotime('2019-07-30');
$secondEndDate = strtotime('2019-08-01');

if (($secondstartDate >= $firstStartDate && $secondstartDate <= $firstEndDate) && ($secondEndDate >= $firstStartDate && $secondEndDate <= $firstEndDate)) {
    echo 'inside range';
}
```

Hope it helps you!!