# How to fix "A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered
>
> Filename: models/finance_model.php
>
> Line Number: 635

This is my code:

```
    $this->db->where('hospital_id', $this->hospital_id);
    $expenses = $this->db->get('expense')->result();
    foreach ($expenses as $expense) {
        if (date('m/y', $expense->date) == date('m/y', time())) {
            $this_month_expense[] = $expense->amount;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how does the output of `$expense->date` look like?

Comment: It's the date expenses recorded.

Comment: if it looks like "01/19" you just do `if( $expense->date) == date('m/y', time()) )`

Comment: to understand what you did wrong, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307005/2275490 and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks Vickel. You are really Awesome human being.